# How to force the C++ only read input that ends with #

Tags: c++

I tried to found the answer on google but didn't find anything,
so, the task is to create a program that will read input(a string of numbers) only with # in the end ("1234#") and count odd and even numbers.

I managed with counter via:

```
char ch;
int odd_number,
    even_number;
odd_number=even_number = 0;
printf("To leave print % : ");
while((ch=getchar()) !='%')
{
    switch (ch)
    {
    case '1':
        odd_number++;
        break;
    case '2':
        even_number++;
        break;
```

but now I've no idea how to make it to read only the strings of numbers with # in the end

Comment: If you want to do that, then first use C++ and not C as language. Then, read a complete line with ````std::getline```` in a loop. If it contains a #, then use the line, otherwise, discard/ignore it. If it contained a #, then you can count your odd and even characters.

Comment: take the whole string and find the size . Now check the last character(size-1) whether it is # or not. Do this in loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is:

- Do all operations in a loop, until user input contains a '%'
- Inform user what to do
- Read a complete input line from the user
- Check, if that is a none empty string, consisting of digity and having an # at the end
- If the line does not fit to the requested format, then ignore it
- Count odds. The number of evens is the rest of the string (without the #)
- Show result to user

Now, translate this design idea in your code.

You must develop you own code.

Anyway, I will provide some example code that you can try to digest, and will make sure that the teacher does'nt believe that it is your solution.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {

    // Stay in program, until input string conatains a %
    for (std::string input{}; std::none_of(input.begin(), input.end(), [](const char c) {return c == '%'; });) {

        // Give instruction to the user
        std::cout << "Enter a number followed by a #  (a '%' in the string will end the program):\n-> ";

        // Get user input and check, if it is a valid numberdfgh
        if (std::getline(std::cin, input) and
            not input.empty() and
            input.back() == '#' and
            std::all_of(input.begin(), std::prev(input.end()), isdigit)) {

            // Count odd numbers
            size_t countOfOdds = std::count_if(input.begin(), std::prev(input.end()), [](const char c) {return c & 1; });

            // Calculate even numbers. That is the rest (without the #)
            size_t countOfEvens = input.size() - countOfOdds - 1;

            //Show result 0 user
            std::cout << "\nNumber contains " << countOfOdds << " odds and " << countOfEvens << " evens\n\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```